# StackOverflow file structure

Tags: discussion, design, stack-overflow

Each stack overflow post has the following structure:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/id/title

Does that mean that the post title is an actual html page stored on the server? Or is the body of the post kept and then inserted into a default html page with the header information and sidebars etc?

What does the id part represent? Is this unique for each question?

Comment: The title part of the url is irrelevant and is only there to make the site more user & search engine friendly. You can go to any question by just providing the ID.

Comment: @Niklas thats useful to know. But as @answered mentioned, how are the pages/posts generated?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network

Comment: note that the title is ignored and only the ID matters (I put a way better question title on this question's URL):  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94042/super-unicorn-extreeeeeme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm nearly certain that the pages are generated dynamically and that the information lives in a database somewhere.  Static pages for posts would be absurd to maintain.  ID is going to be a unique identifier of some kind, yes.

Think of it like this:

```
<<incoming request - contains ID>>

<?php
  $postBody = $dbconnection.query(POSTS_BY_ID, ID);

  echo '<body>';

  echo $postBody;

  echo '</body>';
?>
```

Obviously, there's a lot left out here, but the idea is that the post content can be quickly retrieved by ID, then dropped into the page template.

Comment: @answered so you think that the information is saved maybe as an object in a DB? The object could then maybe loaded into a html template which is generated on the fly? Just trying to get my head around this.

Comment: @Santiago - Most definitely.  The contents of the post live in a column, are retrieved by id when the request comes in, and the page is generated dynamically using the values looked up.  I'll add some pseudo-code shortly.

Comment: @Santiago here is [an MSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network) giving some information about the technology that powers StackOverflow, if it is of interest to you.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to read up on [ASP.NET MVC routing](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs) schema.

ID is the question ID in the database, the name is ignored.